# Create a Swift function with parameters that aren’t allowed to escape the function?

Tags: swift

I have a function that is only valid to call within the context of another function, so I want swift stop consumers from capturing the inner function:

```
protocol Foo {
    func bar(onlyValidToCallInsideBar: () -> Void)
}

class GoodFooImpl {
    func bar(onlyValidToCallInsideBar: () -> Void) {
        // do some stuff
        onlyValidToCallInsideBar()
        // do some more stuff
    }
}

class CapturingBadFooImpl {
    var badCaptureOfOnlyValidToCallInsideBar: (() -> Void)?
    func bar(onlyValidToCallInsideBar: () -> Void) {
        badCaptureOfOnlyValidToCallInsideBar = onlyValidToCallInsideBar
    }

    func fizz() {
        badCaptureOfOnlyValidToCallInsideBar!()
    }
}

class AsyncBadFooImpl {
    func bar(onlyValidToCallInsideBar: () -> Void) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            onlyValidToCallInsideBar()
        }
    }
}

class FooConsumer {
    func buzz(foo: Foo) {
        bar() {
            // This should only be called inside bar
        }
    }
}
```

I want to prevent impls like `CapturingBadFooImpl` and `AsyncBadFooImpl`.

Comment: Ehrm. What? Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Use the `@noescape` attribute.

Comment: @Mattt Argh! Yet another attribute that isn't in any of the references I use. I found out about it by doing a Google search, but it's not in the language reference iBook, not in the Using Swift With Objective-C iBook, not in the Swift Standard Library PDF, nor in the Swiftdoc.org site. Where do you find out about this stuff?!?

Comment: @DuncanC It’s covered in the [latest Swift iBook](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH35-ID348), delete your copy and redownload to get the newer one.  I think it was in the 1.2 release notes.

Comment: It looks like the web version of the book has been updated, but not the iBook. I use the iBook - or at least I have been doing so. Looks like I might need to switch to the web-based version until the updated iBook comes out.

Comment: @DuncanC [iBook has been updated too](http://i.imgur.com/7iwcdUF.png), try deleting your local copy and then redownloading.

Comment: @mattt, it was DuncanC that made that comment, not me.

Comment: @HeathBorders Ah, apologies. Tab autocompletion fail.

Answer (score 1):

Swift has nested functions. It sounds like you want to make your function nested inside another. Or, if you are creating a framework, you can make your function private. That prevents it from being used outside of its module (the framework).

If you don't mean one of those things you're going to have to explain what you want more clearly.

Comment: It sounds like he wants to pass a callback to some client, and the client needs to call the callback synchronously before returning.

Comment: @KevinBallard Yes, this is it exactly. I ended up changing my API, but the question is still valid.